# Is there any possibility of getting a Permanent Residency in UAE?

Tags: immigration, citizenship, indian-citizens, pakistani-citizen, uae

I have heard that more than 35% of the population in UAE is of South Asian origin. A significant number of them have being there since the 70s. So I wonder is there any possibility of getting a PR in UAE, so you won't end up spending there 30-40 years of the prime of your live and then forced back?

Comment: PR = Permanent Residence permit? If so, do spell it out; not everyone who visits this site (and searches it) would know the acronym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only in February 2017 the UAE government has made it possible to apply for permanent residency. Unfortunately, the terms are very restricted--at the time,  [HH Sheikh Mohammed tweeted that the UAE will allow a new entry visa system for "entrepreneurs, pioneers and talented minds in the medical, scientific, research, IT and intellectual sectors.](https://lovindubai.com/dubai/a-new-visa-entry-system-is-going-to-be-introduced-to-make-sure-the-most-talented-people-end-up-in-the-uae)"

If you do not fit these conditions, residency rights can also be granted by virtue of buying property or headquartering a business. But these need to be renewed every two years.

Currently, the UAE does not offer comprehensive options for permanent residency.